# Windows 2000 Server and .NET 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-server-2000

For reasons that I won't get into here, I will be doing some new development a Windows 2000 Server with a SQL Server 7 database.  The existing website housed on this box is running Classic ASP and I will be developing some new capabilities that I was hoping to develop in ASP.NET, preferably MVC, so .NET 3.5 would be what I am shooting for.

Is it possible to setup .NET 3.5 on a Win 2K server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think .net 3.5 is supported on W2K.

Source: [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en)